# Getting started with ASDF package management and Common Lisp

Tags: build, common-lisp, sbcl, asdf

I'm having trouble getting started with `ASDF` and Common Lisp.

How can I get a minimal example working?

Comment: There is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/common-lisp/670/asdf-another-system-definition-facility/2183/simple-asdf-system-with-a-flat-directory-structure#t=20160813133545521621) in the documentation section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer my own question:**

So, how to do your "Hello World!" with `ASDF` build system? Here's what worked for me. I'll help you side-step the time-consuming traps that I fell into.

Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnWVu8VVDbI&index=1&list=PL2VAYZE_4wRIoHsU5cEBIxCYcbHzy4Ypj). He explains installation of `sbcl`, `emacs`, `quicklisp` (a Lisp library manager), [`slime`](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/), and `quickproject`, which sets up a project with `ASDF`.

**Now to side-step a few traps:**

- `slime` didn't seem to work with `clisp`. I had to use [scbl](http://www.sbcl.org/). Note, I'm on ubuntu 16.04.
- You must have your `.asd` file in the path of your `ASDF` system. You can accomplish this by working in `~/common-lisp/`; if you don't have it you can make it. See [here](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Configuring-ASDF-to-find-your-systems) to setup `ASDF` to look in other directories.
- Once you have they system built, load the system with `(asdf:load-system :<system>)`. Also, to access functions in a different package, use the following syntax: `(<package>::<function> ...)`.

Happy coding.

---

**For vim users:** `Emacs` and Lisp, specifically with `quicklisp` and `emacs`'s package manager, is a beautiful combination. Probably because `Emacs` is written in Lisp. I see the value of this. But I'm a `vim` user. I was pleased to find [Evil](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil), a great vim layer for `emacs`. Check out this [4 minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uz_0i27wYbg&feature=youtu.be), which impressed me. Also, [here](http://juanjoalvarez.net/es/detail/2014/sep/19/vim-emacsevil-chaotic-migration-guide/) is a post of another `vim` user setting it up to be like his `vim` environment, better in some cases. *I now think the combination of `emacs` and `vim` is better than either alternative.*

Comment: `PACKAGE::SYMBOL` means you are accessing an internal symbol in the package. You should export any symbols intended for use outside the package (then they can be used with just one colon `PACKAGE:SYMBOL`). Exporting is done by adding `(:export #:symbol1 ... #:symboln)` to your `DEFPACKAGE`.